# Why can't I use an anonymous function inside a thread macro?

Tags: clojure

If I define an anonymous function before using it in a thread macro:

```
(def even #(map even? %))
(-> [1 2 3] even)
```

I get the correct result:

```
(false true false)
```

However, if I evaluate the following code:

```
(-> [1 2 3] #(map even? %))
```

I get the following error:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fn params must be Symbols
```

Why can't I use an anonymous function inside a thread macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread macro inserts the previous form as the second element in the next form.

```
(-> [1 2 3]
    #(map even? %))
```

becomes

```
(fn* [1 2 3] [arg] (map even? arg))
```

you want either:

```
(->> [1 2 3]
     (map even?))
```

or

```
(-> [1 2 3]
    (#(map even? %)))
```